# How to add default values to hasMany in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-2.2

Say I have a domain Books.

```
static hasMany = [reader:Reader]
```

And Class Reader

```
String fullName
```

Now I want to add Readers with fullName: "PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC" by defualt in the Books domain.

Please tell how do I accomplish this? I am pretty new with Grails.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class named `BootStrap` in **Configuration** folder of your App andd add `init()` method to it. This method will be executed before App starts. Example:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init() {
        def readerA = Reader.findOrCreateByFullName("PersonA")
        def readerB = Reader.findOrCreateByFullName("PersonB")
        def readerC = Reader.findOrCreateByFullName("PersonC")
        def readers = [readerA, readerB, readerC]
        def book = new Book()
        for(reader in readers){
           book.addToReader(reader)
        }
        book.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I want readers to be added to Books whenever a new Book is created without my adding readers to it explicitly....

Comment: Ok. You should write custom constructor for Book domain that adds readers to it. The code is exactrly the same, but new book should not be created (readers should be added to `this`).